# Копирование текста из активной ячейки в текстовое поле на форме

Tags: excel, visual-basic

Всем доброго времени суток. Ребят, подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли реализовать такую вещь: есть таблица в excel, сделал форму для подсчета разности значений в двух ячейках (первый текстбокс для значения 1, второй - значение два и третий это результат и кнопочка которая будет выполнять действие подсчета этих значений). Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы значение из выделенной ячейки переносились в текстбокс? И как это сделать? По логике я понимаю, что должно быть такой принцип: если ячейка выделена, то данные переносятся в ячейку 1, потом должна быть по идее проверка пустое первое поле и если да, то со следующей выделенной ячейки заносить данные во второе поле, а по коду нашел только возможность переноса из ранее заданной в коде ячейки.

Comment: Ясли ввод в ячейку - зачем форма? Если есть форма, зачем задействовать ячейку?

Comment: В таблице около 700 записей. записи представляют собой время прихода на работу сотрудника и время ухода (при этом есть промежуточные записи в виде отметок во время обхода территории, которые не учитываются при подсчете, но нужны для суммарной информации) для удобства думал вывести расчет на отдельную форму, вызов которой осуществляется по нажатию кнопки

Comment: Если просто выделили ячейку при просмотре таблицы, значение запишется в поле... Конечная цель какая - получить разность значений из двух ячеек? Для этого не обязательно заносить значения в отдельные поля, достаточно увидеть результат.

Comment: Разобрался как передавать значение в ячейку , а на соседнюю ячейку кинул формулу для расчета разности этих двух колонок))
Спасибо))